# Procedure dialog not available in pgadmin4 version 2.0 in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, pgadmin-4

I am new to postgresql.I would like to convert stored Procedures and functions from MS SQL server. However in the Pgadmin client , the procedure dialog is not available and Function dailog behaves more or less like procedure?

So Functions and procedures are same in the postgresql. How do we distinguish them here?
OS : windows 7 64 bit
EDB server installed : 10.1.3
pgadmin 4 version : 2.0

Please let me know if there is any understanding Gap and if there is some installlation/upgrade, please share the link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with pgAdmin. Postgres simply does not (yet) have stored procedures. And no, procedures and functions are not the same

Comment: well, please have a look at this link  https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/procedure_dialog.html , in which it states in the first line that "procedures are supported by EDB Postgres Advanced Server". Also i did not find the pgadmin4 version 2.1 64 bit installables for windows.

Comment: "EDB Advanced Server" is something different than PostgreSQL - it's the commercial offering of EnterpriseDB. Did you buy that? Or did you just download the community binaries (installer) from the EnterpriseDB website?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : okay, but i when download it ,the icon reads "postgresql_10". I downloaded it from the following link https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads and pgadmin4 is the GUI tool for editing it. Am i on the right track?

Comment: That's the "community edition", not the commercial EnterpriseDB Advanced Server. And that does not have stored procedures, only stored functions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  : so as per discussion, can we conclude that , use Function dialog for creating function and stored procedures in pgadmin 4 client.

Comment: No, you can only create stored functions with that, not stored procedures.

Comment: thanks for the info, so any idea how can i proceed writing SP's with pgadmin 4 version 2.0 using the community edition?

Comment: Procedures and functions are the same thing for Postgres. You can create functions using void as returning data type for the same purpose and abilities with procedure in sql server.